# TensorFlow-Lite Swift setup (bridge-header/includes/root folder)

Tags: ios, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

TensorFlow Lite was recently released. The codebase comes with a [demo ios application](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/simple).

I would like to create/run the same application, but using Swift. I have followed these steps:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/ios.md#using-in-your-own-application

This is not enough.

1) I think what I am missing now is some bridging header.

2) I'm also not sure how these specific Obj-C includes would look in swift:

```
#include "tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/contrib/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/contrib/lite/string_util.h"
#include "tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/mutable_op_resolver.h"
```

3) Must the TensorFlow root directory (200+mb) be included in the packaged ios app?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you'd need to call the TFLite C++ API From Objective-C++. You can make a thin Objective-C++ class to call TFLite, and use it from Swift.

More language support may be coming in the future.

For question (3), the compiled library would just be several hundreds of bytes. Check out the library built by `tensorflow/contrib/lite/build_ios_universal_lib.sh`.